# Facebook Embedded Posts , page width 100%

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

Any one knows how to set [facebook page plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) page plugin width to full page size, or any other way to show page posts in full width (specially on mobile devices).

Thanks

Comment: 500px is the max. width, you can only add a parameter to make it pseudo-responsive (on page load) on mobile devices, but that's it. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin#adaptive-width

Comment: @CBroe  When loading in mobile (Android,Iphone) web view  it shows very small window, Its more than half of web view. That is the problem, Any way to fill that window?